# how to style a placeholder in react bootstrap form <Form.control> element?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

i have this form using react bootstrap form but i dont seem to be able to change the color of the placeholder

```
          {/*Lastname*/}
          <Form.Group>
            <Form.Label style={styles.labels}>
              <h3>Lastname</h3>
            </Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              style={styles.inputName}
              type="text"
              id="creatorLastName"
              name="creatorLastName"
              placeholder="Lastname"
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
```

Comment: Please search Stackoverflow before posting a question. This is easily found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-a-html5-inputs-placeholder-color-with-css

Comment: tried this before, turns out adding !important in the css did the trick